# Storing O-Auth Tokens

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, oauth

I am completely new to O-Auth but I have just implemented my first O-Auth flow in obtaining access tokens from an external API to gather information on users using NodeJS and Express. The external API generates an access token and a refresh token as the access token only lasts for 24 hours.

I am wondering what is the best practice to store API access and refresh tokens as I will have to use them even when the user is not accessing my application to gather information in the background. Would it be just a database and then querying the database on the server side of my application to access the API? Then refreshing the token and updating the entry from within the database?

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on the type of API client you are using. OAuth has standard solutions for the below 3 scenarios. As a next step, maybe let us know which of these scenarios is closest to yours:

- Web UI: gets tokens for an end user, stores then in memory, can deal with access token renewal via cookies
- Mobile UI: gets tokens for an end user, can store them in OS specific secure storage
- Back end process: gets tokens on behalf of itself, stores then in memory and re-authenticates when tokens expire

I would aim to leave token storage to the Authorization Server, which has built in processes to do this in a secure manner.

Risks with a second token store are that a rogue employee could perhaps grab tokens and operate as users - so it is worth thinking about this kind of threat.

Comment: Backend process would most describe mine I think, the user first has to login through a front end for me to get the access token and refresh. Once I have it I am going to just refresh it in the backend as I will be using it constantly even when the user is not logged on in the browser. When you say storing in "memory" for this do you mean a regular variable in the script?

Comment: Could you not use the [Client Credentials Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/call-your-api-using-the-client-credentials-flow) instead? This tends to be the simplest option for back end processes. Or do you have particular requirements about the token needing to contain specific user IDs? In this flow your process would just store tokens in variables.

Comment: That is nearly exactly how I am implementing it at the moment but I need to have it tied to a user account, which in my case gets returned with the access token as an INSTALLED APP ID parameter. At the moment I am testing storing in an AWS database but unsure if I should or not

Comment: So if you could call the API on behalf of a user via a URL such as /users/id/someresource that would give you the simplest and most standard option, preferable to making end user tokens long lived and having to deal with token storage. It feels like an API design question really. I would aim to store recently logged in user IDs rather than tokens. I would then be able to use client credentials flow to operate on those users in the background. Of course, the API might need updating with new operations to enable this.

Comment: Of course, storing tokens in an application database is not out of the question, but is a more complex solution. Most UIs use token lifetimes such as access token = 60 minutes, refresh token = 8 hours. Eventually the refresh token will expire - they do not live forever. Your back end process would need to plan for session expiry, whereas with client credentials flow this would be far simpler.

Comment: I think for now I am going to go down the database route of storing access and refresh tokens. The refresh tokens I am using last 30 days so have a job job refresh them setup which should hopefully overcome that problem and generate a new access token at the same time.